# Can I have in the same Spring project a URL to show my views and another for a REST API?

Tags: spring, rest, api, jsp

I need to create a project able to render views (with JSP) and I need to provide a REST API too.

It's possible to have all of this in the same project?

How will the URLs works to access each things?

Thanks you!

Comment: learn this : https://www.udemy.com/microservices-with-spring-boot-and-spring-cloud/learn/v4/overview

Comment: Use `@RestController` for API and `@Controller` to show views- @RestController anotation is actulally `(@Controller+@ResponseBody)`. So you can mix this up for the solution -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to follow the strict [Roy Fielding-like principles](https://restfulapi.net/) of REST, then probably not.

But if you just want a REST API in a loose meaning, lets say an interface that returns a resource (JSON, HTML, a documents, etc.), sure. Think of it this way. Most web applications (ones that render views) are also going to have some form of AJAX calls, AJAX calls are just calling a REST API (~ish) that returns some JSON (or something) and then JavaScript is going to parse the response and render something on the views.

So, most modern websites that are powered by or assisted by AJAX are going to be a mix of a REST API and a view rendering one.

Hehe. I just made REST developers around the world cringe.

Now, is this a good practice? That is a whole other story. If you are talking about about a large application that is a GUI based and a large application that uses a REST API, normally you don't mix them. Things get confusing and modularity is awesome for maintenance. Also for what it is worth, normally if you are going 100% RESTful, technology you may need for UI development are no longer available since you begin to track state and such. But if its something small or UI related go for it!

As for the URLs, think about this. You tagged Spring so, I am using that.

```
//I will render a view!
@RequestMapping("/blah")
public String blah(Model model){
    return "/view/blah";
}

//I return a JSON string of "/view/blah"
@RequestMapping("/blah")
public @ResponseBody String blah(Model model){
    return "/view/blah";
}
```

Both of these would be inside a `@Controller`, they are both doing the same thing but the `@ResponseBody` in a very, very loose sense, makes the second a REST service, as it tells Spring that what you are returning is the response and not to render a view from it. Granted Spring will only try to render a view if you have a ViewResolver set up.

Baeldung has a [great breakdown](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-controllers) of RESTful controllers versus non in Spring, and yes they can be used in the same application.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can mix in an application a classic [@Controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) with a configuration that provides a view based on JSP and a [@RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) that, as you can read from official javadoc, is a

> A convenience annotation that is itself annotated with @Controller and
>   @ResponseBody.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, only have precaution about the url that you configure in your controllers, with @RequestMapping configure the correct URL for every path in your application.